# ¿Cómo obtener los valores de frecuencia cardíaca de Google Fit History?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-api

Necesito obtener todas las mediciones del ritmo cardíaco, y no el mínimo, el máximo y el promedio, que es lo que he podido conseguir.

Este es el código que uso para leer de mi clase de Java.

```
private void readDataFitnessHistory()
{
    // Setting a start and end date using a range of 1 week before this moment.
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date now = new Date();
    cal.setTime(now);
    long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

    cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -1);
    long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

    java.text.DateFormat dateFormat = getDateInstance();
    Log.d(TAG, "Range Start: " + dateFormat.format(startTime));
    Log.d(TAG, "Range End: " + dateFormat.format(endTime));

    DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
            // The data request can specify multiple data types to return, effectively
            // combining multiple data queries into one call.
            // In this example, it's very unlikely that the request is for several hundred
            // datapoints each consisting of a few steps and a timestamp.  The more likely
            // scenario is wanting to see how many steps were walked per day, for 7 days.
            .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM, DataType.AGGREGATE_HEART_RATE_SUMMARY)
            // Analogous to a "Group By" in SQL, defines how data should be aggregated.
            // bucketByTime allows for a time span, whereas bucketBySession would allow
            // bucketing by "sessions", which would need to be defined in code.
            .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
            .enableServerQueries()
            .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .build();

    // Invoke the History API to fetch the data with the query and await the result of
    // the read request.
    DataReadResult dataReadResult =
            Fitness.HistoryApi.readData(mApiClient, readRequest).await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    DataSet dataSet = dataReadResult.getDataSet(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM);
    showDataSet(dataSet);
    displayBpmDataForToday();


}
```

Gracias!

La respuesta:

```
History:    Type: com.google.heart_rate.summary
History:    Start: 22 sept. 2017 10:40:06
D/DBGPRUEBA History:    End: 22 sept. 2017 10:40:06
D/DBGPRUEBA History:    Field: average Value: 71.13179
D/DBGPRUEBA History:    Field: max Value: 86.0
D/DBGPRUEBA History:    Field: min Value: 55.0
```

Comment: Hola, creo que sólo existe existe la función resumen (com.google.heart_rate.summary) pero he visto que puede extraer los datos por cubos de datos, pero no sé cuál es el período mínimo para el que puede agrupar los datos.

(. bucketByTime (1, TimeUnit. HORAS) 

sería el período máximo de 1 hora o ¿podría fijarse en minutos?

(. bucketByTime (10, TimeUnit. MINUTOS)

Lo he intentado, pero siempre me devuelve sólo un cubo de al menos una hora de intervalo cuando necesitaría que me devolviese todos los cubos posibles que se hayan registrado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola respondo a mi propia pregunta.

Para poder obtener todos los datapoints de las lecturas realizadas con la Api de Google Fit el objeto DataResult a construir sería el siguiente:

```
final DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
   .read(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
   .read(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM)
   .enableServerQueries()
   .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
   .build();
```

Devolvería todos los datapoints entre el rango especificado.