# Acceder a los datos de varios usuarios de Google Fit API Android desde una aplcación android

Tags: android, google-play-services

¿Cómo puedo acceder a los datos de varios usuarios a través de Google Fit API para Android? Mi aplicación muestra una lista de usuario en una activity y al seleccionar uno de ellos debe mostrar los datos de Google Fit History, para un sólo usuario no hay problema. ¿Como lo podrías hacer para varios usuarios?.
Gracias.

La consulta a google History la realizo según este post:
[Consulta Google Fit API History](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/105125/c%C3%B3mo-obtener-los-valores-de-frecuencia-card%C3%ADaca-de-google-fit-history)

La construcción del cliente la realizo según la documentación de Google Fit API,([Ejemplo para para usuario logueado en el terminal](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-fit/blob/master/BasicSensorsApi/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/fit/samples/basicsensorsapi/MainActivity.java)), que sólo valdría para los usuarios logueados a través del terminal, mi requisito sería el usar los datos de login de cada usuario a través de un servido web y con esas credenciales registrarme en el servidor google fit store para recoger los datos.

Comment: hola Ja12.  ¿Puedes mostrarnos tu código, para ver como cargas el historial de un usuario? Enseñanos también lo que has intentado para que salga de varios usuarios y los errores o problemas concretos que tienes. Asi nos contextualizas y podemos ayudarte. **Mira [ask] para aprender a hacer mejores preguntas**. Un saludo

Comment: Lo he intentado exponer un poco mejor y contextualizar. No pongo ningún ejemplo para varios usuarios, porque no sé por donde empezar. Un saludo y gracias.

Comment: Esto es demasiado amplio a mi parecer. Como te decia, has de mostrar lo intentado para poder ayudarte. Intenta hacer el login a traves de un servicio web para recabar los datos y si en el proceso tienes dudas concretas, pregunta aqui siguiendo [ask]. Un saludo

Comment: Lo que quiero es el método que me permita loguearme con las credenciales necesarias, sin tener porque ser una cuenta activa de google en el terminal. Un saludo gracias.

Comment: Pero pedir ese metodo es muy amplio, y es motivo de cierre. Has de investigar e intentarlo. Si durante el desarrollo tienes problemas concretos pregunta aqui ...